# AppCompat action bar color differences (2.3 - 4.2)

Tags: android, android-appcompat

i'm using appcompat action bar in my app.

But i find, that colors of acton bar are different on version 2.3 and 4.2.

In 4.2 is action bar dark
In 2.3 is action bar light

I would like to have same colors in all versions. Is it possible without custom styling?

Thanks for any advice.

[image: 4.2]

[image]

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to diagnose the problem just from two pictures, could you please give us more information? Normally it should have the same color on any API level. In your case you probably have a different style for higher or lower APIs, check the folders inside the res folder for any API selectors like `values-v13` or anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent theme style in "styles.xml" under values-xx should be the same if you want same color in all api levels

It is possible to achieve the higher api parent theme style in lower versions using appcompat

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">   
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, it was caused different values in values-v11 and values-v14 so i deleted them and set theme in values/styles XML file.